# Run javascript when clicking button on vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, onclick

Previously I had a custom button on a custom object and I set behaviour to "execute javascript" and content source to "onclick javascript".

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}
var retrieveDB = '{!Lead.Retrieve_DB_Details__c}';
if(retrieveDB == false){
alert('You cannot perform DB Check with retrieve DB details as false');
}
else{
var result = sforce.apex.execute("RetriveDBDetailsController","getDBDetails",{leadId:"{!Lead.Id}"});
alert(result);
window.location.reload();
}
```

But now I am creating  a Visualforce page which contains a button.

```
<apex:commandButton action=" " value="D&B Check"/>
```

The question now is, how do I call a class by pressing a button on a Visualforce page?

I tried to write controller for the same :

```
public class D_B_LeadCntrlr {

public lead ld {get; set;}
public boolean Retrieve_DB_Details {get; set;}    
public String leadId {get; set;}
public D_B_LeadCntrlr(apexPages.StandardController sc){
    leadId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    if(leadId != null){
        ld = [select Retrieve_DB_Details__c from lead where id=:leadId limit 1];
        Retrieve_DB_Details = ld.Retrieve_DB_Details__c;
    }
}

public void callMethod(){
    system.debug('');
    RetriveDBDetailsController.getDBDetails(leadId);
   // pageReference pf = new pageReference('');
}
```

But having issue with alerts. Please help resolve this

VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="D_B_LeadCntrlr">
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js"/>
<script >

    var success = 'false';
    function myFunction(){
        var Retrieve_DB_Detail = '{!Retrieve_DB_Details}';
        if(Retrieve_DB_Detail == false || Retrieve_DB_Detail == 'false'){
            alert('You cannot perform DB Check with retrieve DB details as false');
        }else{
            var result = sforce.apex.execute("RetriveDBDetailsController","getDBDetails",{leadId:"{!leadId}"});
            alert(result);
             window.location.reload();
        }
    }

    function showSuccess(){
        if(showSuccess == 'true'){
            alert(success);
           window.location.reload();
        }
    }
    </script>
<apex:form >

    <apex:actionFunction name="callMethod" action="{!callMethod}" onComplete="showSuccess()"/>

        <apex:PageBlock >
            <div align="center" draggable="false" >
                <apex:CommandButton value="D&B Check" onclick="myFunction()" />
            </div>
        </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: ahh you wrote javascript code inside apex .. wow is your code succesfully compiled ?

Comment: no thats where I am stuck. I am not understanding how to embed the same functionality in apex

Comment: You wanted to give the Validation Error or only the Javascript Errors? If you want Javascript Errors only then you can give the javascript function in Apex:commandButton itself. By giving the Onclick="JavascriptFunction();" within the commandButton

Comment: I want validations for both the alert conditions if(retrieveDB == false){
alert('You cannot perform DB Check with retrieve DB details as false');
}

var result = sforce.apex.execute("RetriveDBDetailsController","getDBDetails",{leadId:"{!Lead.Id}"});
alert(result);

Comment: @Subhash can you please tell me how exactly can we add the javascript there.

Comment: @Wizard, Check my answer

Comment: @Subhash please check my updated answer. The functionlity works but the field are populated only if i refresh the page. It's not loading by itself..There's something wrong I am doing on vf page can you please help

Comment: After alert(result), Make the variable Success=True and Call the showSuccess() Function. No need of apex:ActionFunction now in the apex:form And Window.location.reload() not working?

Comment: window.top.location='/'+'{!leadId}'; this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try to simplify code :

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="D_B_LeadCntrlr">

<script >


    function myFunction(){
        var Retrieve_DB_Detail = '{!Retrieve_DB_Details}';
        if(Retrieve_DB_Detail == false || Retrieve_DB_Detail == 'false'){
            alert('You cannot perform DB Check with retrieve DB details as false');
        }else{
            callMethod();
        }
    }

    </script>

<apex:form >
<apex:pagemessages />
    <apex:actionFunction name="callMethod" action="{!callMethod}"  />
        <apex:PageBlock >
            <div align="center" draggable="false" >
                <apex:CommandButton value="D&B Check" onclick="myFunction()"  onComplete="return null;"/>
            </div>
        </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Apex:class:

```
public class D_B_LeadCntrlr {
public lead ld {get; set;}
public boolean Retrieve_DB_Details {get; set;}    
public String leadId {get; set;}
public D_B_LeadCntrlr(apexPages.StandardController sc){
    leadId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
    if(leadId != null){
        ld = [select Retrieve_DB_Details__c from lead where id=:leadId limit 1];
        Retrieve_DB_Details = ld.Retrieve_DB_Details__c;
    }
}

public void callMethod(){
    system.debug('');    
    apexpages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,RetriveDBDetailsController.getDBDetails(leadId));
    apexpages.addmessage(msg);
    }

}
```

How it will work:

1. clicking button will call javascript function `myFunction`. Added oncomplete attribute to button to stop reloading of page on button click.
2. Javascript function will perform initial check based on `Retrieve_DB_Detail`. if `Retrieve_DB_Detail` comes to be false it will call action function named `callMethod`.
3. Action will call `callMethod` from apex controller and will add a pagemessage on page based on processing result.

Note that in order to make things simple second alert was modified to pagemessage. Also actionfunction will automatically perform refresh pf page.

Answer (score 0):

Write your VF Page like below

```
<apex:page>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        alert('Coming to the Function');
        //check your if conditions and your remaining code here...
        //For calling the apex class method, You can use the link given below
    }
    </script>
<apex:form >
        <apex:PageBlock >
            <apex:CommandButton value="D&B Check" onclick="myFunction();" />
        </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Link for calling the Method from Javascript

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zaMIAQ

Hope this might helps...